# How to Use Geofence to track others?

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

suppose there are two users of same application.
one is parent and other is child !
so by using Geofence, how father can look after his child activities ?
(i mean how father will get notified when his child enters or exits the created geofence ) ?

Comment: Well that is completely up to you. Please tell what you want that happens. And how.

Answer (score 0):

you can draw a region on particular lat lng, with radius in meter. When child Enter or Exit particular region app will receive a callback, you can send child's status(enter/exit) to server, from server you can send notification to father.